# div not expanding to new content in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div A and another div B inside it. Using jquery i get data and insert into HTML() in div B, div A does not expand its length and div B overflows over the bottom.

Here is its CSS:

```
#A {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width:920px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:left;
}

.B {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 425px;
}
```

Comment: What's the styling for `#B`? Is it floating?

Comment: @Wright-Geek this is your 6th question where someone has had to come back behind you and make it readable. If you are not sure how to make code formatted and readable, please check out the guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: No its not floating, its the right part of 2 inline blocks..

Comment: .B{
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
vertical-align:top;
width:425px;
}

Comment: Have you tried making #A be `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

Might be time to post a link to this one!

Failing more info, perhaps try `height:auto;` on `#A`, or remove `overflow:auto`.

Comment: these do not work, i wish IE was not so different from all the other browsers

Comment: Do you have a DOM inspector in your browser? It may be worth checking to see if there's some residual styles being applied to #A? Perhaps it is inheriting, or perhaps .b in absolutely positioned - sounds a bit strange.